# Multiple Async Calls to a stateful session bean

Tags: asynchronous, ejb, specifications, ejb-3.1

If i have a reference to an stateful session bean with two or more async-methods inside of the stateful session beans.

If i call those async methods (multiple calls) from the same client (which holds the reference to the stateful session bean) are the calls guaranteed to be ordered in the order the client has called it?

I understand the spec that calls from multiple threads to one instance are guaranteed to be serialized (no concurrent execution), but i cannot find any statement in the spec that says something about the order of multiple calls to async method calls.

Answer (score 2):

No, there are no guarantees, similar to ExecutorService.submit.

(I don't know how else to support this assertion other than to say that I helped implement the asynchronous EJB support in WebSphere Application Server.)